# Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to perform file upload test.

I have created an HTTP request to upload the file but I am getting **400** Error.

**Following is the data I am using to perform the test.**

1. The file type is CSV and verified the same by keeping the file in Jmeter bin folder and outside as well.
2. HTTP request which is getting sent to the Server.

**"POST http://staging.server.com/app/abc/upload/nextech"**

**POST data:**
--hHjQWI9uUQ3sP-EYqUUzibD0nxN07P
**Content-Disposition:** form-data; name="file"; filename="appointments - Sheet1.csv"
**Content-Type:** multipart/form-data
**Content-Transfer-Encoding:** binary

--hHjQWI9uUQ3sP-EYqUUzibD0nxN07P--

**Cookie Data:**
JSESSIONID=F12BCDF8EC1BD4B52E18716A174FB347

**Request Headers:**

**Connection:** keep-alive

**Accept:** */*

**Origin:** http://staging.server.com

**X-CSRF-TOKEN:** 44cf8a25-2157-4086-bcd6-828b827f3efa

**Content-Type:** multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9wyB2Bt4GSs1EYtR

**Referer:** http://staging.server.com/app/schedule
Content-Length: 952

**Host:** staging.server.com

**User-Agent:** Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_171)".

**File Path in the request is:** "D:\Jmeter3\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\appointments - Sheet1.csv", **ParameterName:** file, **MIME Type**:multipart/form-data

**Request Header:**
 **Accept**                                 */*

**Origin**                                  http://staging.beepermd.com

**X-CSRF-TOKEN**                            ${extractedCSRF}

**Content-Type**                            multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9wyB2Bt4GSs1EYtR

**Referer**                                    http://staging.server.com/app/schedule

Comment: What is the difference between your **Request headers** and **Request header** sections? It also seems that you have unsubstituted token there `${extractedCSRF}`

Comment: In request header 1, I have shown the data after the request is sent to the server.
In request header 2, I am showing data of the header, which is I am using.

Comment: @AlexeyR. ${extractedCSRF} is a variable which is carrying the value of csrf token.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload the file my expectation is that you should be using `Files Upload` tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

1. Tick `User multipart/form-data` box
2. Switch to `Files Upload` tab
3. Configure File Path, Parameter Name and MIME Type sections:

   [image]
4. Remove `Content-Type` header from the [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) - assuming above setup JMeter will generate proper boundary value itself:

   [image]

---

Be informed that according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you [should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) (which is [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) as of now) so make sure to visit [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page and fetch the latest available version from there asap.